# AngularJs embedding an MS Word doc using a $scope variable as the URL

Tags: angularjs, embed

Embedding a random MS Word word doc, which I found on the internet, works if I hard code the URL:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=https://d9db56472fd41226d193-1e5e0d4b7948acaf6080b0dce0b35ed5.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/spectools/docs/wd-spectools-word-sample-04.doc&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

However, I want to get the URL by AJAX, so I changed the HTML to

```
<iframe src="{{cvUrl}}&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

but even hardcoding that `$scope` variable in my JS:

```
$scope.cvUrl = 
    'http://docs.google.com/gview?url=https://d9db56472fd41226d193-1e5e0d4b7948acaf6080b0dce0b35ed5.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/spectools/docs/wd-spectools-word-sample-04.doc';
```

gives

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.24
```

This seems quite basic - what am I doing wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)`.trustAsResourceUrl`

```
var cvUrl = 
'http://docs.google.com/gview?url=https://d9db56472fd41226d193-1e5e0d4b7948acaf6080b0dce0b35ed5.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/spectools/docs/wd-spectools-word-sample-04.doc&embedded=true';

$scope.cvUrlTrusted = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(cvUrl);
```

and HTML:

```
<iframe ng-src="{{cvUrlTrusted}}"></iframe>
```

<kbd>[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6p244xt/)</kbd>

---

```
<iframe src="{{cvUrl}}&embedded=true"></iframe> <!-- wrong syntax -->
```

or:

```
<iframe ng-src="{{cvUrlTrusted + '&embedded=true'}}"></iframe>
```

doesn't work too because of policy, so you need pass through `$sce` full URL

Comment: Maxim, I cannot understand it - this works perfectly for me, ***BUT***, it I use `localhost` or my real web site, I get 404 "not found". If I copy the "not found" URL and remove the trailing `&embedded=true` I get prompted to download the file, so obviously it does exist. Any idea what I am doing wrongly?

Comment: @Mawg I don't know your project configuration so cannot give you right tip. Try to google `embedded` flag meaning

Comment: I don't see any difference in the code. What can you do with the `embedded` flag, except set it to `true`. I can't find any documentation online - do you have a URL? I am wondering if it is a permission thing - maybe something in `htaccess` ...

Comment: Maxin, can you please look at my followup question? Thanks  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46998298/angular-js-embedding-an-ms-word-doc-using-ajax-return-data-as-the-url

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to import the angularjs predefined services:

**$sanitize, $sce** inject these in your controller and you can replace or redesign the url, beause of if you use directly it will not render that url, because it is one of the **security policy to rendering the unwated thing on webpage,**

In HTML:

```
 <iframe ng-src="{{urlHere}}"></iframe>
```

In JS controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $sanitize, $sce) {
  var Url = 
    'http://yoururl.com.doc&embedded=true';

  $scope.urlHere= $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(Url);
});
```