# AngularJs injection error

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, inject

My sample, very basic, skeleton app works just fine. Then I tried to add @MaximShoustin answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501656/angularjs-embedding-an-ms-word-doc-using-a-scope-variable-as-the-url/46502773#46502773) - Plunk [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e6p244xt/).

And I get

```
jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=inspinia&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.0%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Doc.lazyLoad%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.5.0%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DngSanitize%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fa%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A416%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fa%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A25%253A136%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520b%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fa%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A24%253A188)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Object.module%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fa%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A24%253A431)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520u%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fa%252Fjs%252Fplugins%252Foclazyload%252Fdist%252FocLazyLoad.min.js%253A8%253A2925)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Object.n%2520%255Bas%2520forEach%255D%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fa%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A355)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520u%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fa%252Fjs%252Fplugins%252Foclazyload%252Fdist%252FocLazyLoad.min.js%253A8%253A2994)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fa%252Fjs%252Fplugins%252Foclazyload%252Fdist%252FocLazyLoad.min.js%253A8%253A3048%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Object.n%2520%255Bas%2520forEach%255D%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fa%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A355)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520u%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fa%252Fjs%252Fplugins%252Foclazyload%252Fdist%252FocLazyLoad.min.js%253A8%253A3026)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520new%2520%253Canonymous%253E%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fa%252Fjs%252Fplugins%252Foclazyload%252Fdist%252FocLazyLoad.min.js%253A8%253A3511)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Object.instantiate%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fa%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A41%253A396)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520c%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fa%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A38%253A348)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Object.provider%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fa%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A38%253A290)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520d%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fa%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A234)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fa%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A340%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520n%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fa%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A355)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fa%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A135)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fa%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A304%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520n%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fa%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A355)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fa%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A135)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520fb%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fa%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A43%253A164)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520c%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fa%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A20%253A449)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Ac%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fa%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A21%253A259)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520fe%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fa%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A20%253A69)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520HTMLDocument.%253Canonymous%253E%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fa%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A306%253A372)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520j%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fa%252Fjs%252Fjquery%252Fjquery-3.1.1.min.js%253A2%253A29948)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520k%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fa%252Fjs%252Fjquery%252Fjquery-3.1.1.min.js%253A2%253A30262)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A40%3A60%0A%20%20%20%20at%20n%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A355)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A135)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A304%0A%20%20%20%20at%20n%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A355)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A135)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20fb%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A43%3A164)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A449)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Ac%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A259)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20fe%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A69)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20HTMLDocument.%3Canonymous%3E%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A306%3A372)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20j%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fjquery%2Fjquery-3.1.1.min.js%3A2%3A29948)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20k%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fjquery%2Fjquery-3.1.1.min.js%3A2%3A30262)
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:4526
    at n (angular.js:321)
    at g (angular.js:4487)
    at fb (angular.js:4409)
    at c (angular.js:1691)
    at Ac (angular.js:1712)
    at fe (angular.js:1606)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (angular.js:30423)
    at j (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
```

Here's what ought to be the relevant code to inject `$sce` and `$sanitize` (I added the last two parameters to the controller and the last entry in the module) - what am I doing wrongly?

```
function MainCtrl($rootScope, $scope, $http, $interval, $state, $location, $sanitize, $sce)
```

and

```
(function () {
    angular.module('inspinia', [
        'ui.router',                    // Routing
        'oc.lazyLoad',                  // ocLazyLoad
        'ui.bootstrap',                 // Ui Bootstrap
        'ui.grid',                      // Grid
        'ngSanitize'
    ])
})();
```

beyond that, the only change is to add

```
<iframe ng-src="{{cvTrustedUrl}}"></iframe>
```

into the view

---

[Update]  I injected ngSantize, but now I get

angular-sanitize.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$$minErr' of undefined
    at angular-sanitize.js:19
    at angular-sanitize.js:6
(anonymous) @ angular-sanitize.js:19
(anonymous) @ angular-sanitize.js:6

Comment: Have you included `angular-sanitize.js` in your html ?

Comment: But there are no errors prior to injecting `sanitize` and `sce` ... ? If I remove them, there are no errors in the dev console

Comment: `$sanitize` will only work after adding `angular-sanitize.js` .. did you added that ?

Comment: Lolx - no one told me about that! I thought that it was a standard part of Angular (blush)

Comment: BTW in demo i wrote - imported `angular-sanitize.js` :)

Comment: Thanks, Max (+1). I did that, but please see update to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message contains [a link to the page](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=oc.lazyLoad&p1=Error:%20[$injector:nomod]%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.0%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DngSanitize%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:6:416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:25:136%0A%20%20%20%20at%20b%20%28http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:24:188%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.module%20%28http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:24:431%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20u%20%28http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fplugins%2Foclazyload%2Fdist%2FocLazyLoad.min.js:8:2925%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.n%20[as%20forEach]%20%28http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:7:355%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20u%20%28http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fplugins%2Foclazyload%2Fdist%2FocLazyLoad.min.js:8:2994%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fplugins%2Foclazyload%2Fdist%2FocLazyLoad.min.js:8:3048%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.n%20[as%20forEach]%20%28http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:7:355%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20u%20%28http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fplugins%2Foclazyload%2Fdist%2FocLazyLoad.min.js:8:3026%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20new%20%3Canonymous%3E%20%28http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fplugins%2Foclazyload%2Fdist%2FocLazyLoad.min.js:8:3511%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.instantiate%20%28http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:41:396%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20%28http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:38:348%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.provider%20%28http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:38:290%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20%28http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:39:234%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:39:340%0A%20%20%20%20at%20n%20%28http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:7:355%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20%28http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:39:135%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:39:304%0A%20%20%20%20at%20n%20%28http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:7:355%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20%28http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:39:135%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20fb%20%28http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:43:164%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20%28http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:20:449%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Ac%20%28http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:21:259%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20fe%20%28http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:20:69%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20HTMLDocument.%3Canonymous%3E%20%28http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:306:372%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20j%20%28http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fjquery%2Fjquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:29948%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20k%20%28http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fa%2Fjs%2Fjquery%2Fjquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:30262) where the cause of the problem is explained in human-readable form with a stack of errors:

> Failed to instantiate module oc.lazyLoad due to:
>
> Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/nomod?p0=ngSa...

and

> Module 'ngSanitize' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

`ngSanitize` module should be loaded at the moment when the application is being bootstrapped.

It is also preferable to use unminified packages in order to improve the readability of call stack.

Comment: I have injected it, but now I get a new error (please see updated question). I will research that &should post a new question if necessary

Comment: Angular core packages are suited to work seamlessly with each other. An error like this one that addresses package internals usually means that package versions were mismatched - like in your case. It's 1.5 angular and 1.2.25 sanitize.

Comment: Where do you see that? When I look at the source, it is 1.5, and the whole angular directory came as one with the [Inspinia](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/inspinia-responsive-admin-theme-WB0R5L90S) framework and I have made no changes to that dorectory

Comment: Saw 1.2.25 version in the example you've posted, http://jsfiddle.net/e6p244xt/ . And 1.5.0 was mentioned in the question. If your case is more complex than mismatched versions, I'd suggest to address this problem in a new question and provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the issue.

Comment: Oh, I see (+1) .  The fiddle was someone else's and works. Both of mine are v1.5 and give the problem shown in my updated question. I will research that & post a new question if needed.

Comment: Now, when I click such a link with 1.5, I get an error "`Error: could not handle the request`" :-(

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica The link is likely too long, at least the link that was provided in the OP. Try to truncate it to fit reasonable URL length (2000 chars). Since there was a degradation and the link was workable at the time when the question was posted, consider reporting the issue to https://github.com/angular/angularjs.org/issues , although I'm not sure if it will be ever fixed.